# php how to get the current decimal/thousand separator for a given locale

Tags: php, localization, locale

I've set the locale using the setlocale() function to let's say "en_US".

now I'm trying to format the currency without a thousand separator like this:

> $currency = number_format($value, 2,
>   '.', '');

that works, but sometimes I have other currencies and I want the number_format to use the correct decimal separator according to the use locale.

Is there a way to get the current decimal separator somehow, based on the locale that has been set?

Answer (score 14):

[`localeconv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.localeconv.php) should do it.  From the manual:

> Returns an associative array
> containing localized numeric and
> monetary formatting information.

[Here is a list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39cwe7zf%28vs.71%29.aspx) of language strings recognized by `setlocale()` on Windows.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately that returns empty array elements: [thousands_sep] => [int_curr_symbol] => [currency_symbol] => [mon_decimal_point] =>

Comment: it has something to do with windows. All works well on my mac/linux, but I was looking for a solution to get currencies formatted consitently across our windows dev machines as welL. Oh well. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 5):

It is not the best, but it works:

```php
$locale_info = localeconv();
echo 'decimal_point=' . $locale_info['decimal_point'] . "<br/>\n";
```

[localeconv()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.localeconv.php) returns an associative array with other fields besides the decimal point character.

Answer (score 0):

Sean Bright is right, use `localeconv()` function. Are you sure that you set a correct locale for your OS, because Unix-based OS use "en_US.UTF-8" like notation, while Windows use "en-US".

Comment: If you have different OS on your developer computer and product server, than you can call `setlocale` like this: `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.utf8', 'en-US')`. Function will use first found locale.

Comment: thanks, that sounds like a solution, but still, the array stays empty on windows even with these alternative locales

Comment: Try using locales from [MSDN manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39cwe7zf%28vs.71%29.aspx). `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.utf8', 'american')` works perfectly both on my XP and Vista, returning filled array with currency name and symbol and numeric separators.