# Decimal mark in PHP

Tags: php, localization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php how to get the current decimal/thousand separator for a given locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944245/php-how-to-get-the-current-decimal-thousand-separator-for-a-given-locale)

Can I get the decimal mark in PHP if I know the language/country codes ?

Or is there a public database/csv/specification with this information ?

Comment: You might want to see [money_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php).

Comment: [`money_format()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) will handle the decimal/comma correctly if you know the locale if that's how you intend on using this.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [localeconv()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.localeconv.php). You could do this:

```
$locale_info = localeconv();
echo $locale_info['decimal_point'];
```